AG Grid keeps rows selected after rows are deleted
I have a streamlit app where I use AG Grid to display data. I have a list of favourites, and here I have a button which I can use to delete the favourites. The rows are then deleted in the source, and then the favourites are refreshed.
My problem is that while the data is being refreshed inside the AG Grid, the grid keeps rows selected. E.g. I delete the first 3 rows, they disappear from the grid, but then the new rows that are the first 3 rows are then selected.
favourite_item_table = AgGrid(
    st.session_state.user_favourites.sort_values(by='segment'),
    custom_css=custom_css, 
    gridOptions=get_grid_options('user_favourites', st.session_state.user_favourites), 
    allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
    update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED, 
    height=min(50 + 28 * len(st.session_state.user_favourites), 600),
    key='item_code',
    # columns_auto_size_mode=ColumnsAutoSizeMode.FIT_ALL_COLUMNS_TO_VIEW,
    fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
    enable_enterprise_modules=False, 
    theme='balham'
)

if favourite_item_table['selected_rows'] is not None: 

    selected_rows = favourite_item_table['selected_rows']

    items_to_delete = [row for index, row in selected_rows.iterrows()]
    item_names = ", ".join([item['item_name'] for item in items_to_delete])

    st.write(f"Remove selected items from your favourites? {item_names}")

    delete_selected = st.button("Remove items from Favourites")
    if delete_selected:
        remove_item_from_favourites(items_to_delete)
        
        get_user_favourite_items.clear()
        # st.cache_data.clear()
        setup_user_favourites_session_states(reset=True)
        st.rerun() 

How can I ensure that the AG Grid selection clears after I rerun my app?
